# Creating a Web Navigation Helper Class for MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, navigation

Im a newbie to MVC and trying to use the web navigator class in my MVC application. http://polymorphicpodcast.com/shows/webnavigator/
The class enables us to have stongly typed urls in a central class file.

I have 3 questions:

1. Is this the best way of storing
   strongly typed urls in MVC or does
   MVC has some special helper methods
   which does the same thing.
2. What is the best place for the class
       file to go in e.g VIEW/MODEL or
       CONTROLLER
3. Below is a sample of the Navigation
           class which returns a proper url for
           an image file.
               Instead of passing the UrlHelper object to the I want to
       run this
           class in the System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage
           context (current context).  What is
           the best way of doing this.

**Sample navigator class for images:**

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class IMG
{
    public string AjaxLoading(UrlHelper urlHelper)
    {
        return urlHelper.Content("~/Images/loading2.gif");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. There are many ways to create navigation links for you ASP.NET MVC, whatever works for you is the best.
2. Most would answer that class files should be placed in Model folder. I found it more meaningful to place ViewModel classes in a separate folder and classes used throughout the application (business logic/meat of the application) in a separate file.
3. What you're trying to accomplish seems like a job for extension methods. Here is a good tutorial: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=406&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

What you're doing is on the right track, however, you need to create static classes and static functions/methods for this to work properly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx has some general info on extension methods.

One quick note: To allow usage of all the extension methods you create, you'll need to reference the class/namespace that you placed them in.

There are two methods of doing this:

1. Assuming you've placed your extension methods in MvcApplication1.MyExtensionMethods, Add the following after the

   ```
     <page>
         <namespaces>
   ```

   tag in your application's web.config (Not the View's web.config file)

   ```
        <add namespace="MvcApplication1.MyExtensionMethods"/>
   ```

   Doing so will allow the extension methods to be used in all of your views (.aspx/.ascx) files.
2. Place

   ```
     <%@ Import Namespace="MvcApplication1.MyExtensionMethods" %>
   ```

   at the top of your .aspx/.ascx files. You would need to do this for every file you need    to use the extension methods on (not efficient)

The following is what I implement and it has served me well thus far.

NavigationLink.cs

```
   public class NavigationLink
   {
        string Text {get; set;}
        RouteValueDictionary Routes {get; set;}
        string RouteName {get; set;}
   }
```

NavigationLink.ascx (Place in shared folder for easy access in entire application)

(Note: I wrap the links in < li> < /li> tags because I use lists for all my navigation controls. You can then place these links in any type of list, allowing freedom with the list's class/style.)

```
   <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<NavigationLink>>">

   <% foreach(NavigationLink n in Model){ %>
      <li>
          <a href="<%= string.IsNullOrEmpty(n.RouteName) ? Url.RouteUrl(Routes) : Url.RouteUrl(RouteName) %>">
         <%= n.Text %>
        </a>
      </li>
   <% } %>
```

Menus.cs (Some examples)

```
  public static Menus
  {
       public static List<NavigationLink> MainMenu()
       {
           List<NavigationLink> links = new List<NavigationLink>();
           links.Add(new NavigationLink{
              Text = "Home",
              Routes = new RouteValueDictionary(new { action="Index", controller="Home" })
           });
           return links;
       }

       public static List<NavigationLink> UserMenu()
       {
           List<NavigationLink> links = new List<NavigationLink>();
           links.Add(new NavigationLink{
              Text = "Messages",
              Routes = new RouteValueDictionary(new { action="Messages", controller="UserCP" })
           });
           links.Add(new NavigationLink{
              Text = "Account",
              Routes = new RouteValueDictionary(new { action="Account", controller="UserCP" })
           });
           return links;
       }

  }
```

Now that you have everything setup, calling these functions is simple:

In your view file (.aspx/.ascx)

```
  <ul class="horizontal_menu">
      <% Html.RenderPartial("NavigationLink", MyMvcApplication1.Menus.MainMenu()) %>
  </ul>
```

Having it setup like this allows for different partial views to be created to render out lists of navigation links in different ways and would require that you only build the partial and call it.

Comment: thank you for your response.  sorry for the delay in my response.  Your solution worked fine for me.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your method. There are a lot of ways to do some things so it is quite useful to see a method that someone actually uses.